Error While Trying to Edit Paths
I have been attempting to make a path associated with my opportunity object accessible to certain profiles on our developer SF app. Every time I attempt to edit the path in question, I get the following error message:

This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Aura.loadComponent(): Failed to initialize application.
Unexpected exception occurred while initializing PathAssistantModel

Has anyone seen this error or know why it may be occurring? I think it may be related to the following error I get while attempting to view the path on the lightning record page:

Error on loading Path
You cannot view this Path. Contact your Salesforce administrator for help.

I have searched these errors extensively without finding anything. Permission for all fields within the path are granted to the affected profile, and the affected profile is assigned to the proper global page layout (two solutions presented in a SF help article).

are you a system admin? if no, can you try editing it as system admin?

I can as a system administrator, but we are trying to apply the same permissions to our intern profile
